# Reverse for url not found in python urlpatterns

Tags: python, django

I made URL config

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', lambda request: redirect('stocks', permanent=False)),
  path('stocks', views.stocks.index, name='stocks.index'),
  path('stocks/<slug:slug>', views.stocks.show, name='stocks.show'),
  path('stocks/<slug:slug>/load', views.stocks.load, name='stocks.load')
]
```

These URLs are ok, and they work but not first

```
  path('', lambda request: redirect('stocks', permanent=False)),
```

It gives when I try http://127.0.0.1:8000

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'stocks' not found. 'stocks' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

But if I try http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks all is ok

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should use **`stocks.index`** instead of `stocks`

```
path('', lambda request: redirect('stocks.index', permanent=False)),
```

Comment: Yep thanks. So stupid of me! I'll delete the question

Comment: Well no SO says better not delete questions with answers